# Selecting records with multiple condition in helper in code igniter

Tags: mysql, codeigniter

### helper

```
<?php

function get_gadget_footer() {
$ci=& get_instance();
$ci->load->database();
$ci->db->where('display', 'Footer');
$query = $ci->db->get('gadgets');

foreach($query->result() as $row)
{

  $type[] = array('name' => $row->name, 'type' => $row->type, 'defaultGadget' =>   $row->defaultGadget);
}
return $type;    

}
```

This my helper file which selects the record from gadget table and stores result in array form. In this helper is have one condition for select query as :      `$ci->db->where('display', 'Footer');`

What I need to do if I want to apply two condition for select query as:

```
$ci->db->where('display', 'Footer');
$ci->db->where('defaultGadget','');
```

As select query doesn't accept two where condition I think doing as above is error. What can I do to get the result successfully.

Comment: what is your condition for `defaultGadget` ? post raw sql with your condition

Comment: my condition for defaultGadget is to know if the field is empty or not. And if its empty i want to display the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add second condition as below

```
$ci->db->where('display', 'Footer');
$ci->db->where('defaultGadget IS NOT NULL',null,FALSE);
$query = $ci->db->get('gadgets');
```

or try this

```
$ci->db->where('display', 'Footer');
$ci->db->where("defaultGadget IS NOT NULL AND defaultGadget !=''",null,FALSE);
$query = $ci->db->get('gadgets');
```

Pass second parameter as null and then use your where statement ,third parameter as FALSE is to protect from adding back-ticks

Comment: okey. thank you i will try but i already have one where condition for display field. how can i again apply this condition. I think using two where condition throws error.

Comment: no it will not throw you error see my updated answer when you use another where ,active record adds AND for second where not the where again

Comment: @user254153 doesn't work has no meaning ,you need to be more precise for that ,any error you got or what happened when you use this code ?

Comment: i mean this condition $ci->db->where('defaultGadget IS NOT NULL',null,FALSE); doesnot work. But it give no error only one condition is working.

Comment: @user254153 can you provide the sample data set on which you are trying to run query ,you can add your table schema and some sample dataset on http://www.sqlfiddle.com/ and post the link here so it will be helpfull to find out whats wrong with the query

Comment: actually, there was syntax error made by myself so error was occured. Thank you. Your answer worked for me. Thanks alot.